# When I extend a class, do I call the static functions directly from a subtype or should I use parent:: each time?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, supertype

When I defined a function in a supertype and called without parent:: it gave me and error teling me it's undefined function. I am wondering if I should use parent:: each time or if I am doing something wrong somewhere else.

I have a class, named core, which has an escape() function for escaping strings
I am trying to call this function from subtypes.
**all methods are static.**

Right now I don'T think static methods are inherited. I call all the static superclass methods with

```
parent::mystaticmethod()
```

now. Because static methods are not inherited.

Comment: Please post some example code so we can see what's happening here.

Comment: you don't need to see the code.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan Um, yes we do. We need to see where and when and why you're using `parent::`. We need to see what code produces an error, and know the exact error if you want us to help effectively.

Comment: @Michael I have 400 lines of code project is complex and I am not copying all here. you can vote down if you want. my question is clear. respect or leave please.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan Common practice here is to trim your code down to an example which illustrates your problem or question, not your full 400 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parent::` only when you are going to **override** function in your child class

Best way to explain this is this example:

```
class Parent {
    function test1() {}    
    function test2() {}
    function __construct() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    function test1() {}  // function is overrided
    function test3() {
        parent::test1(); // will use Parent::test1()
        $this->test1();  // will use Child::test1()
        $this->test2();  // will use Parent:test2()
    }
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct() // common use of parent::
        ... your code.
    }
}
```

Practical example (static methods):

```
class LoaderBase {
    static function Load($file) {
        echo "loaded $file!<br>";
    }
}

class RequireLoader extends LoaderBase {
    static function Load($file) {
        parent::Load($file);
        require($file);
    }
}

class IncludeLoader extends LoaderBase {
    static function Load($file) {
        parent::Load($file);
        include($file);
    }
}

LoaderBase::Load('common.php'); // this will only echo text
RequireLoader::Load('common.php'); // this will require()
IncludeLoader::Load('common.php'); // this will include()

Output:
loaded common.php!
loaded common.php!
loaded common.php!
```

Anyways using parent:: is more useful in non-static methods.

As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.

More information here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: More specifically, when you intend to override a function in the child class but also fully implement the parent's method.

Comment: Yep, but sometimes you don't want to implement parent method.

Comment: it's a control class and all methods are static, does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, as `extends` stands for - you may like to **extend** some functions using `parent::` syntax.

Comment: some forums say static methods cant be extended even in dot net

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Php catching up with my demands is making me proud now.